# Imageio Pillow plugin requires Pillow lib

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, python-imageio

Instead of:

```
scipy.misc.imsave(category + '/' + str(i) + '.jpg', image)
```

I am using:

```
imageio.imwrite(category + '/' + str(i) + '.jpg', image)
```

And it's giving me the following error:

> error in image: 6078 - Imageio Pillow plugin requires Pillow lib.

Pillow is installed

What should I look into?

Comment: Have you installed `pillow`? You can install/update it by running `pip install --upgrade pillow`

Comment: Yes, it tells me: Requirement already up-to-date: pillow in c:\users\laura\anaconda3\envs\fer-env\lib\site-packages (6.2.1)

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment or do you have mutliple versions of python?

Comment: Using a virtual environment in this case!

Comment: Then, try running `pip install --target c:\users\laura\anaconda3\envs\fer-env\lib\site-packages --upgrade pillow`

Comment: Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2c/ee/289ddb9884665aba9ad10d88c4edf867b87bcb93e3acbeeac41d30d87865/Pillow-6.2.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
ERROR: imgaug 0.2.9 requires opencv-python, which is not installed.
ERROR: imgaug 0.2.9 has requirement numpy>=1.15.0, but you'll have numpy 1.14.3 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: pillow
Successfully installed pillow-6.2.1

Comment: And this is what I get: error in image: 0 - cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL' (C:\Users\laura\Anaconda3\envs\FER-env\lib\site-packages\PIL\__init__.py)
error in image: 1 - Imageio Pillow plugin requires Pillow lib.

Comment: Have you activated the virtual environment before installing??

Comment: What is the python version in the virtual environment?

Comment: Python 3.7.3 and yes, I installed it when the virtual environment was activated! (Thank you so much so far btw)

Comment: I suggest creating another virtual environment, activate it and install `imagio` using conda instead of `pip` by running `conda install -c anaconda pillow`

Comment: So, I think the error was due to the fact that the python version in the virtual env was 3.7.3 and the version on my system 3.6.5. I now created a new virtual env with 3.6.5 and it works :) Thanks!!

Comment: Glad I could help, I've added an answer to help other people

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this could happen due to one of these reasons:

- You have two versions of python
- You are using a virtual environment created with `conda` and you're installing `imageio` using `pip`.

Either way, you can follow these steps to solve your issue:

- Create a `conda` virtual environment. The following command will create a virtual environment called `env`:

```
conda create -n env
```

- Activate the virtual environment using:

```
conda activate env
```

- Install `imageio` using:

```
conda install -c anaconda pillow
```